# JPA @Version and transaction rollback

Tags: java, jpa, version, rollback

I have an entity called user, that is versioned:

```
@Entity
public class User{
...
@Version
private Long version;
```

and another called Withdrawal, that isn't.

In a periodical @Transactional method in a @Singleton class, I try to update the user based on withdrawals he has performed:

```
for(Withdrawal withdrawal : withdrawals ) {
    User user= entityManager.find(User.class, withdrawal.getUser().getId());
    user.setFunds(user.getFunds() - withdrawal .getFunds());
    entityManager.merge(user);
    withdrawal.setStatus(Withdrawal.Status.OK);
    entityManager.merge(withdrawal);
}
```

If I change the version of the user after he is read, but before he is merged, I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction
```

And the changes to the user are reverted, but the changes to the withdrawal are not, and that's a problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have a time to test it but try this: don't use merge at all. Your withdrawals are attached and your user is attached so the changes will be automatically flushed at the end of the transaction. I assume first merge increments the version of user and the second merge tries to save the state of the use once again (as withdrawal contains user)

Comment: You are correct, the entities are saved to the DB even without using merge. Unfortunately that doesn't change the behavior, I get the exception but the Withdrawal is not reverted.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many possible causes.
Is your database transactional and do you have transaction enabled both on DB and in your application?
How do you get your withdrawal objects? Are they managed entities?

Comment: My DB is PostgreSQL 9.3, which should be transactional from what I understand.

My applisation runs on JBoss 7.1, here's the properties from persistence.xml:

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />

Withdrawal objects are managed entites and are loaded with EntityManager through a typed query:

    List<Withdrawal> withdrawal= entityManager.createQuery("select d from Withdrawal w where w.status = :wtatus", Withdrawal.class).setParameter("status", Withdrawal.Status.NEW).getResultList();